# How to convert a string to an integer inside C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an example formula console calculator and can't find out how to convert the output of the Console.ReadLine() to a integer. Here is a sample of code that I tried.

```
    int A;
    Console.WriteLine("What is number A?");
    String numA = Console.ReadLine();
    Convert.ToInt32(numA) == A;
```

Comment: Well you're calling a reasonable method (although I'd use `int.Parse`) but you need to *assign* the value to `A`. I would suggest at this point reading an introductory book on C#.... Stack Overflow isn't a good place to learn the basics of a language.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(numA) == A;` converts the value entered (`string`) into `int`, then `==` operator compares it with *garbage* (`A` is not initialize) so you have `bool` value which you *throw away* - `;`

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like this:

```
int A;

do {
  Console.WriteLine("What is number A?");
}
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out A));
```

keep asking user until he/she enters the integer value

Answer (score 0):

```
int.Parse(numA)
```

or...

```
int i;
if (int.TryParse(numA, out i) {
    // parsed correctly
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
int A;
 Console.WriteLine("What is number A?");
 String numA = Console.ReadLine();
A = Int32.Parse(numA);`
```

Comment: I fixed it. I found a quick tutorial on C# and have fixed it. No need for more help.